# Multi-hop RDP, high DPI (4K) scaling issue

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, high-dpi

I just replaced my two aging 25" monitors (1920x1080) with two new 27" 4K monitors (3840x2160).  All works well locally with 150% or 175% scaling.  It also works okay when connecting via RDP directly; however, when I connect from that RDP session to another computer via RDP, the fonts get really small and very difficult to read.

Is there a way to make the high-DPI scaling work with nested RDP sessions?

Local Station (ok) -> RDP Station A (ok) -> RDP Station B (too small)

Please note that I need to do multi-hop RDP for my work.  I connect to a Windows 10 box, and then RDP to other stations from there (I cannot connect directly to the other stations).

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this a bit more and got it mostly handled.  I'll share it here, in case it helps somebody.

First off, most of the servers (and some workstations) are VMs (vSphere ESXi 7.x).  To get more resolution options on these, shut down the VM > Edit Settings > Video Card: increase RAM from 8MB (default) to 24MB.  Then power on the VM and use the virtual console to set the desired resolution + scaling (you cannot do this via RDP).

The second thing is that you need to set RDP to Full Screen (Show Options > Display > drag size control all the way to the right) for it to scale properly.